# CodeOSS portable build support?

Tags: visual-studio-code, open-source, portability

I recently discovered Code OSS (vscode under MIT license) and I quite like the idea of building my own version.

For some reason I don't want to explain, I need a portable build of the open license version. I could find anything about this topic on the whole internet, only how to compile to Windows, Linux and macOS, but not to the portable version of each.

The normal version of VS Code has a portable version too, so how am I able to do the same with Code OSS?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I don't understand. What is a "portable build"? [Portable VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/portable) is a _**mode**_ of operation. Not a separate build target. Did you just misunderstand what Portable VS Code is? Or are you referring to something else entirely?